# How should I properly update the gzipped archive by http?

Tags: http, gzip, tar

I'm writing a small utility, that parses the gzipped incremental archive from the web (https://hackage.haskell.org/01-index.tar.gz). The information about this archive (size and hashes) is stored in the json snapshot file (https://hackage.haskell.org/snapshot.json). I have the copy of archive on my disk. The archive updating program runs in background and checks the snapshot.json. And if the archive on the server was updated, the program downloads the part of the archive by http using range request. 
Unfortunately, I ran in the following problem - here are two archives, one is a bit older than the other -

```
-rw-r--r--  1 borboss  staff  59074415 30 май 00:42 01-index.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 borboss  staff  59073328 30 май 00:30 01-index.tar.gz.orig
```

As far as I thought, they content of 01-index.tar.gz.orig (the older one) should be the same as the beginning of 01-index.tar.gz archive. But the analysis shows that they start to differ at position 59066629.
So i have to cut the several kilobytes off the end of my archive and update using range request after that.

How much kilobytes should I cut off the end of my archive to update it properly? Or course I can cut the end of archive, update it, than check the md5 hash through snapshot.json and repeat this procedure with increased amount of bytes to cut, if the md5 hash did not match, but it seems to me that it is a rather dirty hack.

Comment: (a) This is not a question about Haskell; (b) You seem to be assuming that this tar file will only ever be updated by appending data to the end, but I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read carefully about incremental archives